# Variable as sort order

Tags: php, variables, arguments

I have a multi-dimensional array and I'm using this function to sort it by columns:

```
function sort_mul_dim_arr(&$array, $sort_col) {
    array_multisort( array_column($array, $sort_col), SORT_ASC, $array );
}
sort_mul_dim_arr($test_arr, 3);
```

This sorts only in one direction. I want to pass another argument in order to control the sorting direction. Something like this:

```
$dir = "SORT_ASC"; /* = $_GET["sort"] */
function sort_mul_dim_arr(&$array, $sort_col, $dir) {
    array_multisort( array_column($array, $sort_col), $dir, $array );
}
sort_mul_dim_arr($test_arr, 3, $dir);
```

But this doesn't work. Why is that and how can I fix it?

I thought of another way to make it work, which is by using `if else` statement in the main function:

```
$dir = "SORT_DESC";
function sort_mul_dim_arr(&$array, $sort_col, $dir) {
    if ($dir == "SORT_ASC") {
        array_multisort( array_column($array, $sort_col), SORT_ASC, $array );
    } else {
        array_multisort( array_column($array, $sort_col), SORT_DESC, $array );
    }
}
sort_mul_dim_arr($test_arr, 3, $dir);
```

but that's unnecessary. Why use extra lines of code. Besides I'll have `if else` statements for other things, so things will just get more complicated if I use `if else`.

How can I pass a string to the main function and use it as the sorting direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being impatient, I made a search before getting an answer.

First, I wanted to know the type of `SORT_ASC`, so I checked it.

```
echo gettype(SORT_ASC); // integer
```

It turns out that `SORT_ASC` and `SORT_DESC` are integer. Then I checked their values.

```
echo SORT_ASC;  // 4
echo SORT_DESC; // 3
```

So now, Instead of setting `$dir` to `"SORT_ASC"`, I'll will simply set it to `4`.

```
// SORT_ASC     = 4
// SORT_DESC    = 3

$dir = 4;
function sort_mul_dim_arr(&$array, $sort_col, $dir) {
    array_multisort( array_column($array, $sort_col), $dir, $array );
}
sort_mul_dim_arr($test_arr, 3, $dir);
```